# Decryption in android NDK

Tags: java, android, encryption, android-ndk

I have an encrypted string that I am getting from an API. For security reasons, I cannot have the key in java, although it's not that it's going to kill me to have it in java, but still.

This is the code that's working in java:

```
    String content = "some content";
    String privateKey = "secret key";
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(privateKey.getBytes(), "AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
    try {
        Cipher localCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
        localCipher.init(2, key);
        Log.e("error", new String(localCipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(content, 0))));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchPaddingException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It's important for me to not just have the key in NDK, but also the algorithm being used. All this is to make it tougher to actually find how to decrypt if someone is trying to decompile.

Any examples of how to do this in NDK? This is my first time using the NDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to find a C library that does AES decryption. A quick Google check found [this library](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES128-C/blob/master/aes.c), which seems to be pure C, in a single file, which should be easy to implement. As for the base64 part, you can probably find a C library for that too, or just do it in Java, before passing to C.

**Edit:** [This library](https://tls.mbed.org/aes-source-code) looks better, as it supports 256 bit encryption. For more libraries and details, you can refer to this [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_implementations).